# ¿Como puedo invertir esta cadena por partes con Stack?

Tags: java, netbeans, condiciones, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

tengo este ejercicio en donde consiste en ingresar una cadena y un numero y con este invertirlo pero con el tamaño de la cadena y el numero ingresado se divide creando grupos apartir de estos grupos se debe invertir la cadena.

Este es el enunciado

[image: Aqui esta mi enunciado]

Esta es la entrada y salida

[image: Entrada y salida]

Mi pregunta es como hago para invertir la cadena apartir de los grupos hechos

Aqui esta mi codigo

```
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
      import java.util.Stack;

       public class RevertirGrupal {

    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        while (true) {
            String cadenaText = br.readLine();
            String[] parts = cadenaText.split(" ");
            int number = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            String texto = parts[1];

            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }

            proceso(number, texto);
        }
    }

    private static void proceso(int number, String texto) {

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
            stack.push(texto.charAt(i));
        }
        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            strb.append(stack.pop());
        }
        System.out.println(strb);  //aqui invierte toda la cadena, pero no lo hace por los grupos como mencione
    }
}
```

¿Que me recomiendan hacer?, ayuda porfavor.

Comment: Y qué problema tiene tu código?

Comment: El codigo esta bien Invierte toda la cadena osea ejm juan nauj, pero no se como invertir la cadena por los grupos como en el ejemplo que explico en la imagen, que podria hacer ahi en esa parte que me aconsejas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `proceso()` no tienes implementado el invertir la cadena por bloques, lo tienes de forma que te invierte todo el String.

He intentado modificar lo menos posible tu código:

```
private static void proceso(int number, String texto) {
    
    int bloque = texto.length() / number;    
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i += bloque ) {
        // Creo el subgrupo a invertir de tamaño bloque 
        int left = i;
        int right = Math.min(i + bloque - 1, texto.length() - 1); // Caso en que texto.length % number != 0
        
        // Añado a la pila el subgrupo de bloque elementos
        while (left <= right) {
            stack.push(texto.charAt(left));
            left++;
        }
        // Desempilo y añado a strb
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            strb.append(stack.pop());
        }
    }   
    System.out.println(strb);
}
```

Comment: En el segundo test esta bien ya que son grupos de 5, como se debe invertir la cadena tiene 30 caracteres se debe invertir de a 6 osea 30/5 = 6

Comment: Tienes razón karlosandres, perdona. No había leído bien el texto de la primera foto. Te modifico el código para que cumpla lo que buscas

Comment: Bro muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.